# What are fastest data types to use as an alternative to C++ Vectors in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm new to python as a c++ programmer, and I'm making an app that has unforeseeable appends to a list.

I know that numpy has the .append() function, but as far I understand, it makes a second array that's n+new size and copies that to the same lumpy list we had before, in a way it's a basic static array like the ones you create in c++ with int `array[1][2]` etc.

Are Lists the superior choice for this application? As far as I understand, vectors often have different algorithms, such as appending new arrays in a different memory locations, with the last location pointing to the next array etc.

I ran a test with a timer and Numpy.append is about 5x slower than a List, I'm just wondering if I understand this correctly? Are there any alternatives?

Thanks.

I've tried benchmarking, I heard that numpy is way faster than python tuples etc, and I'm wondering if it's for a specific application only, and what other options I'll have

Comment: A list is designed for growth.  It's underlying data is a `c` array that holds pointers, and has a modest growth space.  A numpy array has a fixed size databuffer (c array) and shape and dtype parameters to make it multidimensional.  It isn't designed for growth.  But compiled methods perform fast math on an array, if the dtype is numeric (c integers and floats).  Don't try to imitate list methods with arrays.  Use arrays as descrivbed in the basic docs.

Comment: numpy is a mathematical computation library, not a container class like std::vector. If all you do is append and iterate, there is almost no advantage to using anything other than List. To take advantage of numpy's performance, you need to use it in the numpy style.

Comment: Thanks. the comments answers my question very well.